# How to make ubuntu as my default OS?

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have installed both Ubuntu and windows in my laptop. Every time I switch on my laptop I have to wait and spend some time to select one of this.

Is there any option to set one of this OS as my default OS and when required to boot with other OS I have to press "function" or any other keys ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/302996/making-ubuntu-my-default-os

Comment: Since that question was also a duplicate, I think it would be more appropriate to link to http://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry

Answer (score 1):

Edit in "/etc/default/grub" the line GRUB_DEFAULT=x to the index of the menu entry which should get selected by default. Then change GRUB_TIMEOUT=x to the amount of seconds you like to see the menu.

after that run
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: My knowledge in this field is very limited. Can you make it little more simple.

Comment: I think http://askubuntu.com/a/148097/136991 explains it quite well.